# Basic Pandas filtering works on small dataset, but not large dataset

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I can't post my actual dataset unfortunately, but here is an example of my issue. I am getting problems when I do basic filtering.

I discovered this coincidentally (fortunately?). Whenever I implement the code below on a smaller version of my dataset, I get the right output. In this case, the record that shows up at the bottom.

However, when I implement this code on the larger dataset (millions of records), I do not get that result, but instead, I get the first entry for 1234 (not last). When I swap keep = "last" for "first", I get the right answer for this user. However, this is incorrect.

The weird thing is when I implement the code below, it works on other parts of the dataset; just not the ones with this particular user.

The ID is in int64, datetimestamp is in datetime64[ns], the user is in object. 
I am using pandas 24.xx (work has not approved the most recent version yet)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1234,1234,5678, 5678, 4567, 1122],
                   'time':["2017-08-21 09:44:33.555","2017-08-21 09:44:33.555", "2018-08-21 10:44:34.000", "2019-08-21 11:44:34.000", "2016-08-21 12:44:34.000", "2015-08-21 13:44:34.000"],
                   'user':["_HGX87A","_HGX87A","HBA001","THC002","THC002","THC003"],
                   'status':["Incomplete","Active","Pending","Expired","Expired","Expired"],
                  'action' :["paper", "document", "approval", "document", "document", "document"]})


raw = df.copy(deep = True)
test1 = raw[raw.time < "2017-08-22 00:00:00.000"]
test2 = test1[test1.status != "Pending"]
test3 = test2.sort_values(by = ["time"]).drop_duplicates(["ID"], keep = "last")
test3[test3.ID == 1234]


I would expect this:

1   1234    2017-08-21 09:44:33.555     _HGX87A     Active  document
```

Edit: I discovered the issue. When I sort as I do above by the timestamp, the issue is records with the exact same timestamp. Even though they have the exact same timestamp, the 1234 "Incomplete" swaps places with the 1234 "Active" as if the 1234 "Active" comes first. But logically, it is impossible to have events occur in this order.

Is this the expected function of pandas? I would have thought that if they were the same, it would keep the position the same (i.e., keep the index ordered).

Secondly, is there a way to modify the code above to maintain the position if there are duplicate time stamps, but still sort by datetime?

Comment: Ummmm i get the expected output

Comment: Yes, I know. So do I. But when I apply this exact same code (just call the larger dataframe), I do not. This is the problem.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I think this is a bug in pandas once the dataframe gets too large